# Is setting pointer to null an allocated memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, null, allocation

I am reading a code which initializes a pointer to null, initially I thought the code was not allocating new memory to the pointer for storing 2d array of values (which it does) which made me wonder, is a pointer initialized to a null pointer an allocated memory?

```
class Int8_tSet : public GridSet
{
public:
  int8_t** set;
//
//
  Int8_tSet():set(0) {}
  Int8_tSet( const Int8_tSet& x ):set(0) {copy(x);}
  virtual ~Int8_tSet() { Free2DArray(set);}
//
// --- opeartor
  int8_t  operator() ( IntVector2D x ) const {return set[x.i][x.j];}
  int8_t& operator() ( IntVector2D x ) {return set[x.i][x.j];}
// --- function
  void Set();
  void Set(int8_t val);
  void Set( IntVector2D x ){ NS_GRIDDATA::Set(x,*this,(int8_t)-1); }
  void Set( IntVector2D x,int8_t val){ NS_GRIDDATA::Set(x,*this,val); }
  void Switch();
// --- output & input
  void Output(std::ostream& out ) const;
  void Input (std::istream& in  );
// --- copy & substitute
public:
  void copy( const Int8_tSet& x ) {NS_GRIDDATA::Copy(*this,x,(int8_t) -1);}
  const Int8_tSet& operator = ( const Int8_tSet& x );

  void Extract(IntVector2D &ll, IntVector2D &ur,Int8_tSet &subgrid) const;
};


void Int8_tSet::Set()
{
  if(!set) {std::cerr<<" Memory not allocated. Call Set(x) first \n"; exit(1); }
  std::fill(set[0],set[0]+size.i*size.j,-1);
}
```

I realized its allocating memory in void Set.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Post some code and try to specify what you're actually asking about. But a null pointer does not point anywhere, so it also does not point to any dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Angew Sadly a null pointer points somewhere, to address 0 :-) there was an exploit in Linux based on mmap(ping) something on the page 0 and waiting for a null to be dereferenced.

Comment: @xanatos OK, from the point of view of implementation, it points somewhere, and it depends on the HW architecture where (it's 0 on x86, but that's by no means a given). But from the point of view of the language, it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: If your question is "is it a dynamically allocated memory" then the answer is no, unless the pointer itself has been allocated dynamically. A pointer is just a built-in type that holds a value, just like an `int` or a `bool`. Is a `bool` set to `false` an "allocated memory"? Yes and no, depending.

Comment: @Angew Sorry about that, I have added the code I was reading.

Comment: What does `"void Set"` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is a pointer initialized to a null pointer an allocated memory

I guess that would mean something like:

```
type* ptr = NULL;
```

In this case memory is allocated for the pointer itself (about the variable `ptr`) - that is `sizeof(type*)`.
**BUT** it does NOT point to an allocated memory, so `delete ptr;` is **NOT** necessary (but still safe).

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a "known invalid" value. It's a valid value for the pointer, but it's generally not safe to dereference a pointer with a null value (an old HP compiler I used let you dereference null and it always returned "0"). You can use it to check if the pointer is valid.

```
if (ptr == 0) // in C++ use 0 (or better still nullptr) rather than NULL, 
{
   ptr = malloc(...);
}
doSomethingWithPtr(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Unless you use manually allocate memory with new, malloc, calloc a.o., it will not allocate memory on the heap by itself. Initializing it falls into the same category.
A pointer may still point to something even though you have deleted it/deallocated the memory.

```
{
    char *dp = NULL;
    /* ... */
    {
        char c;
        dp = &c;
    } /* c falls out of scope */
    /* dp is now a dangling pointer */
}
```

This is a dangling pointer example from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is used to specify when a pointer points to an invalid address, that is, when the pointer points to "anything" because is not in use.
The habit of initialize pointers with `NULL` is to make sure when a pointer is in an *uninitialized state* or in a *memory pointed by the pointer was released yet* state.
The last is the reason because is a very good habit to set the pointer to `NULL` after deleting the memory pointed by it: In C++ for example, `operator delete` checks first if the pointer is `NULL` to don't do any deletion.

Also `NULL` is used as sentinel in situations where pointers are used as argumments (`NULL` means *invalid input* for example).

Answer (score 0):

For,

> ```
>       is a pointer initialized to a null pointer an allocated memory?
> ```

NULL pointer is one which it points to "0"th in memory location pointed by the variable. 
Say,
      int * var=NULL;

0x104 |---------------------|  ---|
      |       0             |     | 
0x100 |---------------------|     | User memory ara
      |       .             |     |
      |       .             |  ---|
      |                     |
      |---------------------|  ---|
      |                     |     |
      |---------------------|     |    OS memory area
 0x0  |---------------------|  ---|

Say, 'var' as a variable get stored in the memory address 0x100 to 0x104 in 32 bit machine. If you store 0 in the value place of 'var' and dereferencing as *var which result in accessing 0x0 location which is belongs to OS memory area. It violates the segment, porocess should access only user space in all the cases, except on certain OS calls.

So, NULL initialiation means not a valid address stored in the variable. Never access the memory area other than user memory area.